# How to calculate the average value of adjacent rows?

Tags: python

I have a text file like the one below:

```
apple_1 1 1 2
apple_2 2 3 4
apple_3 3 5 6
book_1  1 4 5
cook_1  2 4 3
cook_2  4 6 9
book_1  2 3 4
```

The numbers in each row, except for the first column, are random.
What I need is the average value of adjacent rows.
for the case above, the result should be like:

```
apple 2 3 4
book 1 4 5
cook 3 5 6
book 2 3 4
```

The values in 'apple' were the average values of the first three rows.
The values in 'book' were the average values of the 4th row (no changes)
...

Does anyone know how to conduct this through Python?
Many thanks for any comments/suggestions.

Comment: I think users would find it useful if the mentioned text file was included in this question.

Comment: label 'book_1' occurs twice in your table - is it a typo?

Comment: No, the elements in the 1st column may occur repeatedly

Comment: @Jack what is then re rule for dealing them? if `book_1` and `book_2` are both occurring more than once, how should they be combined?

Comment: Also, there are multiple questions here: do you know how to read the file? If yes, please specify how exactly you do it, so that we could offer a solution appropriate to the data structure that you have (pandas DataFrame, numpy array, list of list or something else.)

Comment: Hi, @Roger V., the number in the first column (after '_') means the order of adjacent rows needs to be averaged. In the table, the first three rows have the same element 'apple' and adjacent, so values in those three rows were averaged. Since the 5th row is not 'book_2', so the average value of 4th row is itself.

Comment: Hi, @RogerV., this is a TEXT file, so it could be read as a list, a numpy array, or DataFrame

Comment: @Jack I understand that, but it is not clear from Q what your problem exactly is: 1) how to read a text file, or b) how to do the required calculation, or c) both (in which case it should be two questions.)

Comment: What is the output supposed to be? Another text file, or some Python data structure? And what if an average isn't an integer, for example average of 4, 4 and 5?

Comment: @RogerV. thank you very much, my question is how to calculate, not how to read this file.

Comment: Hi @KellyBundy, it is supposed to output in a text; it is fine if the average value is not an integer, since the actual values in my file are floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the "trigger" for dumping the averages is the occurrence of a key ending in "_1" providing there have been values accumulated previously.

Therefore, without the aid of additional imports I would suggest:

```
def averages(lst, n):
    for v in lst:
        yield v / n

def dump(prev, cols, count):
    if prev:
        print(prev, *averages(cols, count))

with open("example.txt") as data:
    cols = []
    count = 0
    prev = None
    for line in data:
        key, *values = line.split()
        m = map(float, values)
        fruit, n = key.rsplit("_", 1)
        if n == "1":
            dump(prev, cols, count)
            count = 1
            cols = list(m)
            prev = fruit
        else:
            for i, v in enumerate(m):
                cols[i] += v
            count += 1
    dump(prev, cols, count)
```

**Output:**

```
apple 2.0 3.0 4.0
book 1.0 4.0 5.0
cook 3.0 5.0 6.0
book 2.0 3.0 4.0
```

**Note:**

Output does **not** match that of the OP but subsequent comments indicate that the values are actually float

Answer (score 1):

While using pandas, as in @Roger V.s answer, if probably sensible, you could do it without any other packages. For example (assuming your data is in a file called `data.txt`):

```py
with open("data.txt", "r") as fp:
    # read in the data
    data = [line.split() for line in fp]

# list for storing mean data
meandata = []

# initial values
name = data[0][0].split("_")[0]
sums = [int(d) for d in data[0][1:]]
count = 1
for i in range(1, len(data) + 1):
    if i != len(data) and data[i][0].startswith(name):
        # add to sums while row start with the same name
        for j in range(len(sums)):
            sums[j] += int(data[i][1 + j])
        count += 1
    else:
        # get the averages
        meandata.append([name])
        meandata[-1].extend([int(s / count) for s in sums])

        if i != len(data):
            # reset to next name and initialise the sum
            name = data[i][0].split("_")[0]
            sums = [int(d) for d in data[i][1:]]
            count = 1
```

The output is:

```
meandata
[['apple', 2, 3, 4], ['book', 1, 4, 5], ['cook', 3, 5, 6], ['book', 2, 3, 4]]
```

I expect this could be shortened and neatened further without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
    average = []
    l = [[x[0].split('_', 1)[0],x[1],x[2],x[3][0]] for x in [y.split(" ") for y in f.readlines()]]
    curr = ''
    count = 1
    sum = [0,0,0]
    for x in l:
        if x[0] != curr:
            average.append([curr, sum[0]/count, sum[1]/count, sum[2]/count])
            curr = x[0]
            count = 1
            sum = [int(x[1]), int(x[2]), int(x[3])]
            
        else:
            count +=1
            sum = [sum[0] + int(x[1]), sum[1] + int(x[2]), sum[2] + int(x[3])]
        
    average.append([x[0], sum[0]/count, sum[1]/count, sum[2]/count])
    average.pop(0)
    print(average)
```

Comment: This may work with the data shown in the question but isn't easily adaptable if the input lines have more than 4 columns

Answer (score -2):

After clarifications in the comments I suggest the following solution (where I assume that the data are represented by a list of lists):

```
data = [['apple_1', 1, 1, 2],
        ['apple_2', 2, 3, 4],
        ['apple_3', 3, 5, 6],
        ['book_1', 1, 4, 5],
        ['cook_1', 2, 4, 3],
        ['cook_2', 4, 6, 9],
        ['book_1', 2, 3, 4]]

res = []
name = ''
for line in data:
    # print(line)
    n = line[0].split('_')[0]
    if name != n:
        if name != '': 
            res.append([name] + list(s/N))
        name = n
        s = np.array(line[1:])
        N = 1
        print('\n', name, s, N)
    else:
        s += np.array(line[1:])
        N += 1
        print(name, s, N)
res.append([name] + list(s/N))
```

The result is again a list of lists:

```
[['apple', 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
 ['book', 1.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 ['cook', 3.0, 5.0, 6.0],
 ['book', 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

**Old answer**
You could read the file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file_in_quotes, sep=' ')
```

Separator might be a tab ('\t') or something else - one has to see in your file. Since the file is not given, I simply create the DataFrame by hands;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'apple_1': [1, 1, 2],
                   'apple_2': [2, 3, 4],
                   'apple_3': [3, 5, 6],
                   'book_1':  [1, 4, 5],
                   'cook_1':  [2, 4, 3],
                   'cook_2':  [4, 6, 9],
                   'book_1':  [2, 3, 4]}).T
```

There are many ways how one could arrive to the desired result. For example:

```
names = ['apple', 'cook', 'book']
res = pd.concat([df[df.index.str.startswith(name)].mean(axis=0) for name in names], axis=1, keys=names).T
```

where `res` is

```
         0    1    2
apple  2.0  3.0  4.0
cook   3.0  5.0  6.0
book   2.0  3.0  4.0
```

This is not exactly the same as indicated in the OP, since it likely contains an error: index `book_1` occurs twice.

Comment: OP clearly states that the input data are in a file

Comment: @CtrlZ it was discussed in the comments. Apparently they have no difficulty reading a file (which the OP didn't provide.)

Comment: Unfortunately, your output doesn't match the stated requirement

Comment: @CtrlZ you mean the old answer, which was written before the OP clarified their post?